# Django, form in menu and form in view conflicting

Tags: django, forms, django-forms, validation

I want to put a form in my menu to be able to choose a project, keep this information and be able to change it at all time in the site. I'm using a context_processor to implement it and (trying to) use session variable to keep the information.

However I bumped into a problem. The form is included in the base template which is included in all other templates. Some these other templates also contain a form and apparently there is a sort of conflict between the menu form and the other ones. For example, when I try to validate a view form, it tells me that the menu form fields are not filled in, and it shouldn't care about it.

I tried to put a different action url with no effect.

Is what I'm trying to do even possible ? If so, how can I avoid the conflicts ?

The form for the menu is called in a context_processor, the code of the function calling it :

```
def display_select_proj(request):
        if request.method == "POST":
                form = SelectForm(request.POST)
                if form.is_valid():
                        proj = form.save()

                        request.session['proj'] = proj

        else:
                form = SelectForm()
                proj = ""

        return {'select_form': form}
```

I added the `display_select_proj` to the `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` and finally in the base template  i display it with  `{{ select_form }}`

Comment: Your question is confusing. However, a start would be to post the code that is causing the problem, and the error message you are seeing.

Comment: I added a bit of code in my question, but I don't have a specific error. I just can't validate my form without having to fill in the forms contained in the views. It is a problem as I really want the menu to be independant

Comment: What about your template? and your view code?

Comment: It doesn't seem that confusing to me. Basically, they have a form generated via context processor (the "menu form") and another one generated by the page's view function (the "view form"), and the menu form is preventing the view form from validating.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what @Mike described. I can't really put more useful code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have two forms, you need to have something to tell you which form actually got submitted. This will tell your `display_select_proj` function whether to try to validate the form.

Usually, with a plain old form, you have a Submit button, and if you have two of them, the `value` for each submit button is different so you can check it to tell which form got submitted. Failing that, you need to add a hidden field to tell you which form got submitted.

Once you can determine which form got submitted, you can then use that to figure out if you need to bind a form or leave it unbound. For example, in your code, if your project selector has a Submit button named "action" with value "Change Project":

```
def display_select_proj(request):
    if request.method == "POST" and (request.POST.get("action", "") 
        == "Change Project"):
        form = SelectForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            proj = form.save()
            request.session['proj'] = proj
    else:
        form = SelectForm()
        proj = ""

    return {'select_form': form}
```

Note that *every* form will need the extra check to see if that particular form has been submitted.